# Opensearch Grafana: how to visualize text fields

Tags: string, boolean, logstash, grafana, opensearch

this is my first ever post on stackoverflow

Im sending json logs from filebeat to logstash to opensearch to grafana
and everything is working perfectly (if it comes to integer data)
i can even see that opensearch receives my string fields and boolean fields and even reads them.

but when i want to make a dashboard to visualize some strings and booleans, it only finds my integer fields

Can someone help me visualize Strings on grafana and not only numbers.

[this is an image of what i can see when i try to select data, i only see the number field names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8FyM.png)

thanks andrew, now i see this, but i want to only see 1 field
and not all of them
[logs added to grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWKYF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Logs panel

And an example of how I use - the request is something like this:

```
{namespace=~"$namespace", stream=~"$stream", container =~"$container"} |= "$query"
```

But I'm using fluent-bit + loki

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Andrew, im pretty new to grafana but i followed your instructions and i already see the logs field on grafana, we're getting closer thanks!

But i cant do anything else with all these logs. i cant put a new screenshot in here can i?

I want for example the boolean field the only field to be displayed

Comment: I would recommend getting familiar with the LogQL syntax
https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/